# Missing PageShow event in Android 2.2

Tags: android, cordova, jquery-mobile, pageshow

I have an issue i've been encountering with Android 2.2 and 2.3.3 avd/phone but not if i use intel atom image for avd. I'm using phonegap 2.3.0 and jqm 1.3.0.
I'm missing a pageshow event on a page and my application gets broken meaning navigation doesn't work anymore:

```
    03-19 16:09:13.045: I/CordovaLog(2733): Found log level DEBUG
03-19 16:09:13.045: I/CordovaLog(2733): Changing log level to DEBUG(3)
03-19 16:09:13.055: I/CordovaLog(2733): Found preference for useBrowserHistory=true
03-19 16:09:13.055: D/CordovaLog(2733): Found preference for useBrowserHistory=true
03-19 16:09:13.065: I/CordovaLog(2733): Found preference for exit-on-suspend=false
03-19 16:09:13.065: D/CordovaLog(2733): Found preference for exit-on-suspend=false
03-19 16:09:18.395: D/CordovaLog(2733): mobile init
03-19 16:09:20.785: D/CordovaLog(2733): init pgSplash
03-19 16:09:20.995: D/CordovaLog(2733): page before show: pgSplash
03-19 16:09:21.285: D/CordovaLog(2733): pageshow : pgSplash
03-19 16:09:21.355: D/CordovaLog(2733): init
03-19 16:09:22.035: D/CordovaLog(2733): Falling back on PROMPT mode since _cordovaNative is missing.
03-19 16:09:22.285: D/CordovaLog(2733): device ready
03-19 16:09:22.295: D/CordovaLog(2733): check version
03-19 16:09:23.795: D/CordovaLog(2733): init pgLogin
03-19 16:09:24.045: D/CordovaLog(2733): page before show: pgLogin
```

It's missing the pageshow event for pgLogin and navigation gets broken.
I'm binding with :

```
$('[data-role=page]').live('pageshow', function (event, ui) {

         lastPage = $.mobile.activePage.attr('id');
         console.log('pageshow : ' + lastPage);
...
});
```

As you can see in log i get mobile init event from jqm, i get device ready event from phonegap and the 1st page : pgSplash triggers all events: init, page before show, pageshow. But after that it gets broken.
On 4.1 emulator /galaxy tab device it works without any problems.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using jquery `1.9`? live is depreciated as of `1.9`. Start using `on` instead of `live`

Also why not use page id? instead of `[data-role=page]` and see?